# Wix - change the installation folder based on privilege

Tags: wix, wix3

I have to create an installation package using Wix. If an admin user is installing the package, it should install into %programfiles%/[applicationName], if the user is an non-admin user then it should install into its local profile folder( LocalAppDataFolder).

How it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this for [ClickThrough](http://wix.sourceforge.net/ctvision.html) a long time ago. Solution from that looks a lot like this (You provide a Property called "ApplicationFolderName"):

```
    <Property Id="A" Secure="yes" />

    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationFolder" Name="App" />
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Condition Message="Must specify TARGETDIR property when doing an administrative install.">Installed OR (ACTION="ADMIN" AND TARGETDIR&lt;&gt;"")</Condition>

    <CustomAction Id="TARGETDIRtoA" Property="A" Value="[TARGETDIR]" Execute="firstSequence" />

    <CustomAction Id="SpecifiedA" Property="ApplicationFolder" Value="[A]" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="PerMachineInstall" Property="ApplicationFolder" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ApplicationFolderName]" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="PerUserInstall" Property="ApplicationFolder" Value="[LocalAppDataFolder]\Apps\[ApplicationFolderName]" Execute="immediate" />

    <InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="SpecifiedA" Before="LaunchConditions">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="PerMachineInstall" Before="CostFinalize">NOT Installed AND ACTION="INSTALL" AND A="" AND (ALLUSERS=1 OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND Privileged))</Custom>
        <Custom Action="PerUserInstall" Before="CostFinalize">NOT Installed AND ACTION="INSTALL" AND A="" AND (ALLUSERS="" OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND (NOT Privileged))</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 3):

Overriding ProgramFilesFolder property as following should work:

```
<SetProperty Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Value="[AppDataFolder]" Before="CostFinalize"><![CDATA[ NOT Privileged]]></SetProperty>

<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My Folder">
        ...
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I used this to create a 64 bit installer that could install all it's things into `Program Files (x86)` based on a condition in the SetProperty element that does the overriding like this: `<SetProperty Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]" Before="CostInitialize">`

Answer (score 0):

Set property [ALLUSERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to 2. See also [Single Package Authoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).